# Why do we not use @var in authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])

  if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to admin_url
  else
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Invalid user/password combination" 
  end

end
```

Here why user is declared as a local variable instead of instance variable @user?

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the view doesn't need access to the `user` object. It just instantiates it to see if it's a valid user and it authenticated properly, then it redirects to the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't generally need to access the user variable outside the action

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because there's no view needed for this action.  The action contains an if else block that both redirects so there's no use for instance variables.